# Is it redundant to use K-Fold CV with holdout method?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation

I am reviewing some code, a condensed version of which is shown below. It takes an original design matrix $X$ and response vector $Y$, performs a train-test split (yielding `X_train`, `y_train` and `X_test`, `y_test`), and then performs Stratified K-Fold cross validation on the training portion only.  Shouldn't the `StratifiedKFold` object split `X, y` instead of `X_train`, `y_train`, and shouldn't the `GridSearchCV` object also fit the entire dataset as well? With the current approach, it seems that the original dataset is just being reduced by 40% before cross-validation takes place.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=random_state
)
clf1 = LogisticRegression(random_state=random_state)

pipe1 = Pipeline(
    [
        ["sc", StandardScaler()],
        [
            "fs",
            SelectFromModel(
                estimator=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=random_state),
                max_features=50,
                threshold=-np.inf,
            ),
        ],
        ["clf", clf1],
    ]
)
pipe1_param_grid = [
    {
        "clf__C": [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0],
        "clf__multi_class": ["ovr"],
        "clf__solver": ["newton-cg", "liblinear"],
        "clf__penalty": ["l2"],
        "clf__class_weight": ["balanced", None],
    }
]
pipe1_grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe1,
    param_grid=pipe1_param_grid,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(
        n_splits=gridsearchcv_n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=random_state
    ).split(X_train, y_train),
    scoring="f1_weighted",
    n_jobs=n_jobs,
)
pipe1_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually the correct methodology. This is because here k-fold CV is used to tune the hyper-parameters, i.e. selecting the best combination of values for these parameters:

- For each combination of values, a model is trained with the training set of k-fold CV, then evaluated on the corresponding test set. Naturally the process is iterated $k$ times (this makes the estimated performance more reliable).
- At the end of this process the combination which obtains the highest performance of values is selected.

At this stage it is still possible that the selected combination is the best by chance: selection process is a form of training, and any training can cause overfitting. This is why the final model (using the selected values) must be evaluated on a fresh test set, as done after the code shown in the question, I assume.